# Wordpress 4.1 header image problem

Tags: images, headers

I want to use a moving .gif as my header image in wordpress 4.1. In previous versions I could skip the cropping step and leave the image as is, and it would let me pick a moving gif as my header image.
But this update takes me to the wordpress customizer and wont let me move forward without clicking "crop image" and when I do, it throws me an error and I can't set my header image anymore...

Any help? thanks